# how to trigger an event from a property change in one class in another class?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

i have the following class structure and im trying to trigger an event in class when theres a change in a property in another class. the prop property in class C is bound to a checkbox element so every time a user ticks or unticks that box - so when it changes from true to false or vice versa  - i want to deliver that message to class A so it can run 
MethodTriggeredByChangeinProp. I need class A to know which instance of class B and also which instance of class C in B is triggering that method. the only thing i can think of is making listC an observablecollection and adding the propertychanged event in class B but then i get confused about where to go from there and liking it to class A. any help is appreciated! thanks.

```
public class A{
    List<B> listB;

    void MethodTriggeredByChangeinProp(){
    }
}

public class B{
    List<C> listC;
}

public class C{
    public bool Prop{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with just `INotifyPropertyChanged` and keeping track of "owners".

Class C will keep track of property changes, but will accept a `B owner` and an `A notifyMe` objects on construction:

```
    public class C : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public C(B owner, A notifyMe)
        {
            Owner = owner;
            PropertyChanged += notifyMe.MethodTriggeredByChangeinProp;
        }

        public B Owner { get; private set; }

        private bool prop;
        public bool Prop
        {
            get => prop;
            set
            {
                prop = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Class B doesn't actually need to be anything special, unless you want to know when an object of Class C is added to your list - then you need the `ObservableCollection` setup; otherwise, `List<C>` is fine.

Class A's `MethodTriggeredByChangeinProp` changes slightly:

```
    public class A
    {
        public List<B> listB;

        public void MethodTriggeredByChangeinProp(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is C responsibleC)
            {
                var responsibleB = responsibleC.Owner;
                var changedProp = e.PropertyName;
            }
        }
```

You now know the responsible instances of class B and class C in A whenever a property changes in C.

You may also want to take a look at the [Observer Pattern in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-implement-an-observer) for a more in-depth configuration.